# android apk: Change frames per second (FPS) between 20 to 60 FPS

Tags: android, frame-rate

I am working on creating an app for different FPS values, Changing between 20 to 60 FPS.

For this i am trying to add milliseconds delay while rendering frame. 
Is there any similar app available?
How Apps like youtube controlling fps (60 FPS & 30 FPS) ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at libgdx library for writting games.
In Android where you can't garantee the time it takes to process each frame you can do something like this pseudocode:

```
one_frame_expected_time = 1000 milliseconds / FPS; //FPS is 24, 60, etc

while(!endLoop){
    record init_time_in_millis.
    render your frame.
    record end_time_in_millis.
    time_it_took_to_render_frame = end_time - init_time.
    delta_to_expected_time = one_frame_expected_time - time_it_took_render_frame
    if(delta_to_expected_time > 0){
       Thread.sleep(delta_to_expected_time);
    }else{
       //frame time lost. If it happens often you have to lower the FPS.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!endLoop){
        record init_time_in_millis.
        render your frame.
        record end_time_in_millis.
        time_it_took_to_render_frame = end_time - init_time.
        delta_to_expected_time = one_frame_expected_time - time_it_took_render_frame
        if(delta_to_expected_time > 0){
           Thread.sleep(delta_to_expected_time);
        }else{
           //frame time lost. If it happens often you have to lower the FPS.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this code only answer?